# How to perform mouse hover and click a link by using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to Selenium and my use case is using Selenium to automate an appointment booking workflow (https://app.courtreserve.com). The challenging part is that I can't hover over "Book a Court" and click the options in the sub-menu. I attached a screenshot here, and I want to click "Indoor".

[image]

I looked into multiple posts about this and still couldn't figure out why my code doesn't work in this case.

My code is

```
# Set up the driver, and log in.
respMenu= driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="respMenu")
book_a_court = respMenu.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value ="//a[contains(.,'Book a Court')]")
indoor = respMenu.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value ="//a[contains(.,'Indoor')]")
ActionChains(driver=driver).move_to_element(book_a_court).click(indoor).perform()
```

The HTML is:

```
<ul id="respMenu" class="ace-responsive-menu" data-menu-style="horizontal">
  <li class="fn-ace-parent-li " data-sm-show=true>
    <a href="#" data-sm-show=true class="parent-header-link">
      <span>Programs</span>
    </a>
    <ul>
      <li class="fn-ace-parent-li ">
        <a href="/Online/Events/List/5881">
          <span>List</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fn-ace-parent-li ">
        <a href="/Online/Events/Categories/5881">
          <span>Categories</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fn-ace-parent-li ">
        <a href="/Online/Calendar/Events/5881">
          <span>Calendar</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fn-ace-parent-li ">
        <a href="/Online/MyProfile/MyEvents/5881">
          <span>My Programs</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fn-ace-parent-li ">
        <a href="/Online/MyProfile/MyWaitingLists/5881">
          <span>My Waitlisted Programs</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="fn-ace-parent-li" data-sm-show=true>
    <a href="#" data-sm-show=true class="parent-header-link">
      <span>Book a Court</span>
    </a>
    <ul>
      <li class="fn-ace-parent-li">
        <a href="/Online/Reservations/Bookings/5881?sId=294">
          <span>Indoor</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fn-ace-parent-li">
        <a href="/Online/Reservations/Bookings/5881?sId=295">
          <span>Outdoor </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fn-ace-parent-li ">
        <a href="/Online/MyProfile/MyReservations/5881">
          <span>My Reservations</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

which contains `respMenu`, `Indoor`.

The error message I got is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: https://app.courtreserve.com/Online/Portal/Index/5881#mm-2 has no size and location
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way, first, perform the hover operation and then click.

```
driver.get(url)
# get the xpath of the element to hover on
element_to_hover_over = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/header/div/nav/div[2]')
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
hover.perform()
# then get the xpath of the list(which is inside the hover element) to click 
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/header/div/nav/div[2]/ul/li[1]').click()
time.sleep(2)
```

the above mentioned xpaths values are just for example.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem is that you are doing all steps in a single command. Generally you need to hover, then wait for the submenu to appear, then click the desired element. Something like

```
# Set up the driver, and log in.
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

book_a_court = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Book a Court']")
actions.move_to_element(book_a_court).perform()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Indoor']"))).click()
```